# Unable to get metadata for Core Data Persistent Store

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, restkit

I am using RESTKit backed by Core Data. I am trying to detect whether or not I have a new core data model version. I have it set up to map changes automatically I just need to detect the migration to update the UI. My code is:

```
NSError *error;
NSURL *sourceURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Model" ofType:@"momd"]]
NSDictionary *sourceMetadata = [NSPersistentStoreCoordinator metadataForPersistentStoreOfType:nil URL:sourceURL error:&error];
BOOL needsMigration = ![[self managedObjectModel] isConfiguration:nil compatibleWithStoreMetadata:sourceMetadata];
```

The sourceMetadata variable is always nil and I can't seem to figure out why. The error message is not very helpful to me:

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134000 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134000.)"

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is that `sourceURL` is the path of your model file:

```
NSURL *sourceURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Model" ofType:@"momd"]]
```

That is, `Model.momd`, in the app bundle. You need to use the path to your persistent store file, probably `$SOMETHING.sqlite` and probably in your app's documents directory.

Error 134000 is `NSPersistentStoreInvalidTypeError`, which Apple describes as "Error code to denote an unknown persistent store type/format/version". That suggests that either something's wrong with the persistent store file at your URL or that maybe it's missing. The first thing to do is look at `error` and see what `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` is trying to tell you. There's a good chance that it's telling you exactly what's wrong, but that you're not listening.

If a file exists at that URL, it *might* help to change the first argument to the lookup call from `nil` to `NSSQLiteStoreType`, or whatever store type you're using.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not help. The source URL changed to "/Users/me/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/36AA5BE5-2108-4C21-82CB-07A93F7C9D84/data/Containers/Data/Application/F7EB68D1-6E06-4D00-A777-9B9C6D6BAF75/Documents/Model.sqlite" but I still got the same error

Comment: Thanks Tom. I have changed from nil to NSSQLiteStoreType but that did not make a difference. If I go to the path in finder, I see my expected Model.sqlite. The error unfortunately is not more helpful. The above is literally all that it says

Comment: Thanks for the help Tom. Turns out I was using urlWithString instead of fileURLWithPath when I updated to reference Model.sqlite. Switching to fileURLWithPath fixed it

Comment: Yep my apologies. For some reason when I switched to use the Model.sqlite, I switched how I was setting the NSURL